# Not able to find cloudfront distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I am looking into an existing deployment setup, and I can see in route53 that for a subdomain XXX.example.com there is CNAME entry which is pointing to a cloudfront url: xxxxx.cloudfront.net.

This is static site and is accessible on 'XXX.example.com', but I can't find any cloudfront distribution with this URL 'xxxxx.cloudfront.net'. There is only 1 cloudfront distibution listed which is for some other site.

How can I find from where content for 'XXX.example.com' is coming then?
BTW if I directly try to browse cloudfront url 'xxxxx.cloudfront.net', I get 'This xxxxx.cloudfront.net page can’t be found' error but 'XXX.example.com' works.

Comment: Maybe `xxxxx.cloudfront.net` doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @Marcin In that case 'XXX.example.com' shouldn't be accessible. This static content is coming from somewhere, I need to find from where.

Comment: Is Route53 a simple  record? Maybe you see failover content which you get using failover record?

Comment: @Marcin Yes it's simple record, no failover specified.

Comment: @HarshveerSingh facing same issue , did you find answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/amplify-education/serverless-domain-manager/issues/95#issuecomment-419686986). Under API gateway, Custom Domain Name